# Insert text between a rectangle drawn in SVG

Tags: html, animation, text, svg

I have a code in SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="250" height="250" style="fill:blue">
        <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Now I need to add a text between this `rectangle`. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I assume the lack of a space between your `version` and `xmlns` attributes is a typo just in your posting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto line-wrapping in SVG text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "between". If you mean "centered horizontally and vertically", then this would do it:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="250" height="250" style="fill:blue" />
  <text x="145" y="145" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">
    Hello World
  </text>
</svg>
```

Did you mean something else?

If you are talking about having text filling the rectangle—multiple lines of text wrapping at the edges of the rectangle onto a new line—then you should see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text) instead.