# SVG: text inside rect

Tags: svg, text, rectangles

I want to display some text *inside* SVG `rect`. Is it possible?

I tried

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red">
      <text x="0" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue"> Hello </text>
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert text between a rectangle drawn in svg.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449899/insert-text-between-a-rectangle-drawn-in-svg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert text between a rectangle drawn in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449899/insert-text-between-a-rectangle-drawn-in-svg)

Answer (score 331, accepted):

This is not possible.  If you want to display text inside a rect element you should put them both in a group with the text element coming after the rect element ( so it appears on top ).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have to manually set height and width on the rect?

Comment: Depends on the situation and what you mean by 'manually'. You can script in in JavaScript if you like (see narendra's answer below)

Comment: Using my html knowledge - which might well not apply here - it seems like the `g` element has an implicit size here and I'd like the rectangle to expand to it's size.

Comment: The group fits to its content not the other way. I think the elements are still relative to the parent svg.

Comment: is the group element important here?

Comment: @dmo, No at all. However, it may be useful when we want to do styling or transformation that affects for both rect and text elements as a group.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Width and Height can be set to `100%` instead of `100`, which is much better.

Comment: Great answer, this solution worked in my case as well. Thank you! Also, I did specify a group as the answer mentions.

Comment: I think this is a better case for me - https://codepen.io/techhysahil/pen/POJWpW

Answer (score 75):

Programmatically using [D3](http://d3js.org/):

```
body = d3.select('body')
svg = body.append('svg').attr('height', 600).attr('width', 200)
rect = svg.append('rect').transition().duration(500).attr('width', 150)
                .attr('height', 100)
                .attr('x', 40)
                .attr('y', 100)
                .style('fill', 'white')
                .attr('stroke', 'black')
text = svg.append('text').text('This is some information about whatever')
                .attr('x', 50)
                .attr('y', 150)
                .attr('fill', 'black')
```

Comment: This produces markup that *displays* like OP wants, but it doesn't do what OP is trying to do (which isn't legal).  This still produces `<svg><rect/><text/></svg>`.

Comment: Javascript != SVG. The question is tagged with svg, text and rect. Nothing indicates that the user has access to a programming language. (Making this remark since I came here looking for a static solution.)

Comment: While its true this doesn't pertain to the question me and apparently many other people came here for D3

Comment: Is it possible to autofit the rect to the width of the text

Comment: @Colin D That's what I am looking for too. But It looks impossible to expect it  done  automatically. Instead, we have to do so manually by ourselves to achieve that. It will need some measurements of dimension (width and/or height) of both elements (rect and text).

Answer (score 35):

You can use [foreignobject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) for more control and placing rich HTML content over rect or circle

```html
    <svg width="250" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="aquamarine" />
        <foreignobject x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250">
            <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <div>Here is a long text that runs more than one line and works as a paragraph</div>
                <br />
                <div>This is <u>UNDER LINE</u> one</div>
                <br />
                <div>This is <b>BOLD</b> one</div>
                <br />
                <div>This is <i>Italic</i> one</div>
            </body>
        </foreignobject>
    </svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Unlike the `text`-tags-only option, this one actually placed the text inside the path instead of hiding it in some invisible space above it! The `x` and `y` attributes weren't necessary for me but the `width` and `height` were or it also was nowhere to be seen!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Only drawback is that IE11 doesn't support foreignObject; but support for this browser is going away, so this might not be an issue. It is way simpler than using a bunch of tspan.

Comment: Dont use foreignObject, its not supported properly, and likely never will be with browsers like Safari. It has bugs since a decade back https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113

Answer (score 6):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <g>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(145,200,103);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(132,168,86);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="220" height="30" class="GradientBorder" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  <text x="60" y="20" font-family="Calibri" font-size="20" fill="white" >My Code , Your Achivement....... </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically display text over rect using basic Javascript

```js
 var svg = document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')[0];

        var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        text.setAttribute('x', 20);
        text.setAttribute('y', 50);
        text.setAttribute('width', 500);
        text.style.fill = 'red';
        text.style.fontFamily = 'Verdana';
        text.style.fontSize = '35';
        text.innerHTML = "Some text line";

        svg.appendChild(text);

        var text2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        text2.setAttribute('x', 20);
        text2.setAttribute('y', 100);
        text2.setAttribute('width', 500);
        text2.style.fill = 'green';
        text2.style.fontFamily = 'Calibri';
        text2.style.fontSize = '35';
        text2.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
        text2.innerHTML = "Some italic line";

       
        svg.appendChild(text2);

        var text3 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        text3.setAttribute('x', 20);
        text3.setAttribute('y', 150);
        text3.setAttribute('width', 500);
        text3.style.fill = 'green';
        text3.style.fontFamily = 'Calibri';
        text3.style.fontSize = '35';
        text3.style.fontWeight = 700;
        text3.innerHTML = "Some bold line";

       
        svg.appendChild(text3);
```

```html
    <svg width="510" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="510" height="250" fill="aquamarine" />
    </svg>
```

[image]