# Adding text in circle svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have a circle in a svg which is this

```
<circle style="fill:none;" cx="203.00464" cy="289.69531" r="91.29858"/>
```

I want to add some text inside this circle to the top left most point of the circle to the bottom most right point inside the circle. I am able to add the text just fine however I'm struggling with the maths of how to get the text to fit perfectly inside the circle. All I know is what is above inside the `<circle>` but these can vary from one svg to another.

I am able to display the text because I have a `<div>` element that displays inside of a foreignObject. This displays fine its just the position and sizing I'm finding hard because currently everything is manual which is not ideal

How do I work this out I'm using javascript and jQuery to do all this as well as snap.svg to do animation.

Comment: According to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732550/3365426, i'm not sure that it is possible

Comment: I am able to display the text because I have a <div> element that displays inside of a foreignObject. This displays fine its just the position and sizing im finding hard because currently everything is manual

Comment: Just be wary that I don't think foreignObject is well supported, for example I don't think IE supports it for IE11 and below.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for warning me