# Add text inside a dynamic created HTML <rect> element - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have HTML rect element that i am creating dynamically from the TS file. I want to add text inside the shape, how can i dot it?

current code:

```
 const toolTipNode = this.createSvgElem('rect', {
                'x': elementPositionX,
                'y': elementPositionY,
                'width': '300',
                'height': '100',
                'class': 'click-tooltip'
            });
            this.renderer.appendChild(this.layoutSvg, toolTipNode);
```

[EDIT]

Let say that I create in the same way a text element, How can i add the text inside?

```
  const text = this.createSvgElem('text', {
                'x': elementPositionX,
                'y': elementPositionY,
                'width': '300',
                'height': '100',
                'class': 'click-tooltip'
            });
```

Comment: just need to create text element and append in rect

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725288/svg-text-inside-rect

Comment: @xdeepakv Thanks for the replay. Is it the only option? (I wanted to avoid that)

Comment: i  think this works : ```const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello world!');
  this.renderer.appendChild(toolTipNode, text);```

Comment: This is the way canvas work, u have to draw it. without draw it wont work. u can create util function to simplify it.