# Set custom text for material icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use icons from `import FiberNewIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FiberNew";`

Is it possible to set a custom text into the icon?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible because the icons are SVG objects usually.

Comment: Can I use for example some other icons where I can put custom text?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: `@mui/icons-material` https://mui.com/components/material-icons/

Comment: Ok Peter, unfortunately, you can't use that kind of icon library to add text to the same icon itself. The only thing that I can think you can do is make your own icon and use it with a prop that can receive a text and render it where you want.

Comment: @PeterPenzov you can do that using a styled `div` although the result may not look 100% like the icon in your question.

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: I thing this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725288/svg-text-inside-rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned icon belongs to an icon package so you can't change it even with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725288/svg-text-inside-rect) (mentioned in the comments). to check it, open the `FiberNewIcon` source file, is there any usual `SVG`? definitely No.

Since the `FiberNewIcon` is a simple text block, you can create it with simple HTML/CSS properties, let's do that:

```
import React from "react";

const MyIcon = ({ title }) => (
  <p
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "black",
      color: "white",
      fontSize: "40px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      display: "inline-block",
      padding: "15px 8px 15px 8px",
      borderRadius: "12px"
    }}
  >
    {title}
  </p>
);

const Sample = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <MyIcon title={"New"} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <MyIcon title={"Delete"} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

[Live in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-icon-r60d3?file=/src/App.js)

**Note:** You may need to add your custom `fontFamily` property to the icon style.

**Note:** you can pass some styles properties to the `MyIcon` props to control them from the parent component.

**Note:** You can also use the relative units (`rem`, `em`, `%`) to decorate your icon style to have a nice responsive result.

Comment: The code from the sandbox cannot be compiled.

Comment: I've update the broken link, please take a look @PeterPenzov