# In HTML5, can I make an irregular shaped text box?

Tags: javascript, html, text

Just to be clear, I am not starting with a rectangular text box and floating around an irregular image. I am creating an arbitrary shape then typing in text to best fit into this shape.
Is there a jquery plugin or in html5 canvas? Is this even possible yet?

Comment: There is one CSS3 module that defines this behavior (text filling custom shapes), but I don't remember which one it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to provide boxes which describe the shape, you might be able to use [CSS3 Regions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-regions/). Availability in your target browsers might be pretty poor though. This is probably the spec Šime mentioned.

SVG also claims support for this in an [SVG 1.2 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/flow.html). I'm not clear whether this has made it to a W3 Recommendation, or whether it's actually supported in browsers.

Update: [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text) suggest the SVG approach won't work right now.

Answer (score 2):

The [working standard for HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) outlines the current features. The functionality you desire is not mentioned in the working standard, so you will need a script.

[Creative Text Boxes](http://creativetextboxes.com/) looks to provide the functionality you need.