# D3 tree chart, expand node with text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use the following D3 tree chart, however I'm running into an issue, where if the text is larger than the box/node, it overflows.

I'd like to use this same tree structure, but have the box/node expand with the text, and possibly word wrap at some point. In the fiddle, I you'll see the leftmost node's text is overflowing.

Lengthen any of the name fields in the data, to see what I'm talking about:

```
var root = {
"name": "flare",
```

EDIT: I'm trying to support IE9+, it doesn't appear foreignObject is supported in IE9+

Is anyone able to tweak this JSFiddle to do just that? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMa2y/412/)

Comment: This question has appeared numerous times in different contexts, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007640/fit-text-into-svg-element-using-d3-js) or [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/6571949).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks, I was able to get foreignObject working, but then I found out it doesn't support IE9+