# Time axis in d3.js with specific time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, charts

I am using `d3.time.scale()`(reference [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#scale)) to create time scale and providing tick values using `axis.tickValues([values])` ([here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues)). The ticks are rendered for the specified Date objects provided in [values]. 

All fine, but the tick values representations are always in current time zone of the browser. Now comes the requirement to show it in a specific time zone (say, 'Asia/Calcutta'). Is there a way to achieve this? The max option I see is for formatting the ticks, but not replacing them with custom values, which doesn't help the case.

**EDIT**: This might be achieved using an external library like *moment.js*, but it is preferred if this could be avoided.

Comment: I see a method at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16764067/1048860 but would be great if there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No.. I am looking for something the axis automatically handles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timezones are such a pain in the ass.  But if you couple `d3` with the the excellent [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), this task becomes pretty easy with a `tickformatter` function:

```
// create reference to current zone
var currentTZ = "local";

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(10)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
      console.log('format');
      if (currentTZ === "local")
        return moment(d).format('hh:mm:ss');
      else
        return moment(d).tz(currentTZ).format('hh:mm:ss');
  });

  // when user picks a new zone, re-draw axis
  ...
  .append("select")
  .on('change', function(d){
    currentTZ = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].text;
    svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
      .call(xAxis);
  })
```

Here's a full working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="moment.js@2.10.2" data-semver="2.10.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="moment-timezone-with-data@0.4.0" data-semver="0.4.0" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
    <style>
    /* set the CSS */
    
    body {
      font: 12px Arial;
    }
    
    path {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: grey;
      stroke-width: 1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var currentTZ = "local";

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .orient("bottom").ticks(10)
      .tickFormat(function(d){
          console.log('format');
          if (currentTZ === "local")
            return moment(d).format('hh:mm:ss');
          else
            return moment(d).tz(currentTZ).format('hh:mm:ss');
      });

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
      .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.close);
      });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = [{
      date: moment().add(0, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(1, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(2, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(3, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(4, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(5, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(6, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }, {
      date: moment().add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
      close: Math.random() * 100
    }]

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.close;
    })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-65)"
      });

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
    
    d3.select("body")
      .append("select")
      .on('change', function(d){
        currentTZ = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].text;
        svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", ".15em")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-65)"
          });
      })
      .selectAll("option")
      .data(['local'].concat(moment.tz.names()))
      .enter()
      .append("option")
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      });

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is principally helpful. But with the constraint of adding another library(I'm afraid of having no such liberty).

Answer (score 9):

Based on the solution by Mark, here is a working solution ***without using external library***. Enter the Time zone id (e.g. - Europe/Berlin) in the text field.

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 50
},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var currentTZ = "local";

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {

    if (currentTZ === "local") return d3.time.format('%X')(d);
    else {
        console.log(currentTZ);
        return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d.toLocaleString('en-US', {
            timeZone: currentTZ
        })));
    }
});

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
})
    .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.close);
});

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
    date: new Date(0),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(1800000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(3600000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(5400000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(7200000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(9000000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(10800000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}, {
    date: new Date(12600000),
    close: Math.random() * 100
}]

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.close;
})]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
});

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

handleClick = function () {
    currentTZ = document.getElementById('timeZ').value;
    console.log(currentTZ)
    svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function () {
        return "rotate(-65)"
    });
};
```

```css
 body {
     font: 12px Arial;
 }
 path {
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 2;
     fill: none;
 }
 .axis path, .axis line {
     fill: none;
     stroke: grey;
     stroke-width: 1;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Change Time" onClick="handleClick()">
<input type="text" id="timeZ" value="local">
</form>
```

Comment: One thing to consider is that `toLocaleString()` is not supported in some browsers like Safari.