# How to break a line in d3.axis.tickFormat?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to write a function, that returns a tick label with two lines of text. As I can see, an svg text tag is used for text labels. Is there a way to add tspan there or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include newlines in labels in D3 charts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the elements created by the `axis`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6b9j/3/)

```js
d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(180, 10)')
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text') // `text` has already been created
  .selectAll('tspan')  
  .data(function (d) { return bytesToString(d); }) // Returns two vals
  .enter()
  .append('tspan')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('dx', '-1em')
  .attr('dy', function (d, i) { return (2 * i - 1) + 'em'; })
  .text(String);
```

Also, you'll have to set `.tickFormat` to `''` on the `axis`.

Comment: I guess technically you could abuse `.tickFormat` to return text that contains the right tags, although you might have to mess around with namespaces to make that work.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think the text returned by `tickFormat` is [consumed by `.text`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js#L45), and it cannot be used directly to _inject_ tags as text labels (it'll escape them).