# Can not break long sentence in a D3-generated SVG text

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I want to break long sentence into two line in my SVG text that is generated by D3. But I can't do it in `D3/javascript`. I tried with `\n` and `<br/>`, but they are not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {top: 80,left: 70, bottom: 80,right: 100},
        height = 660 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        width = 1320 - margin.left - margin.right;

    var chart = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

    chart.append('text')
        .attr('x', 100)
        .attr('y', 100)
        .text("I want to have this \n sentence in two lines")
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-family", "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("font-size", "16px" )
        .style("fill", "#1ABC9C");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check my answer out, and don't use text function.

Comment: I changed and checked my answer, now it works. check it out and let me know if it works for you as well.

Comment: In SVG, use several `tspan` elements -- see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts

Answer (score 4):

Use `.append("foreignObject").append("xhtml:span").html("your text <br> will goes here");` instead of `.text()` function.

Example:

```
var mytext=svg.append("foreignObject").attr("width"100).attr("height",50).append("xhtml:span")
.html("Your Text <br> goes here");
```

You dont need the br tag here the text will automatically wrapped in to the next line when specified width is reached.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that Mehran is right - you MUST use `.append("tspan")` for multiline SVG text. +1 vote for Mehran. I also just wanted to bring to your attention recent [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810659/linebreaks-from-json-for-d3-js/20812652#20812652). You'll see very similar solution with `.append("tspan")` If you need to programatically split the string into several lines (with the ability to define "width" for splitting), there is also a function wordwrap2() there. I spent a lot of time finding the right function for that purpose, this one is well tested.

There are also other questions on this topic, maybe you'll find something useful there:

[How do I include newlines in labels in D3 charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts)

[Breaking text from json into several lines for displaying labels in a D3 force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810659/linebreaks-from-json-for-d3-js/)

[How to break a line in d3.axis.tickFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058622/how-to-break-a-line-in-d3-axis-tickformat)

[Auto line-wrapping in SVG text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text) (alternative approach with "foreign objects")

Comment: Note that the name of the element is `tspan` and not `span`. There is no `span` element in SVG.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
var textNode = chart.append('text');
textNode.attr('x', 100)
    .attr('y', 100)
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-family", "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("font-size", "16px" )
    .style("fill", "#1ABC9C");
textNode.append("span").text("I want to have this");
textNode.append("br");
textNode.append("span").text("sentence in two lines");
```

Comment: I tried as you said, it doesn't give me any output. I did inspect element, I see this line `<text x="100" y="100" dy="1em" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; fill: #1abc9c;"></text>`. it doesn't have the text that I have given in `.html()`.