# Breaking text from json into several lines for displaying labels in a D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, force-layout

I am new to d3.js and coding in general. This is my question:

*I am trying to find a way to break long displayed names of force layout objects in lines.*

I would like to be able to determine where to break these lines, and I am guessing this is something that might be possible to be done from the json file.

I am aware that there have been similar questions asked already, but I just can't find where to put the code or why my previous attempts haven't been successful. This is the code that I have:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 800,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(120)
    .charge(-600)
    .gravity(.06)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);


  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")  
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 3 || 10; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

// Divide text

text.append("text")       
    .each(function (d) {
    var arr = d.name.split(" ");
    if (arr != undefined) {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                .text(arr[i])
                .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "tspan" + i);
        }
    }
});

// Divide text

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#9ecae1" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#ffffff" // expanded package
      : "#ffcc50"; // leaf node
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  } else {
    // This was a leaf node, so redirect.
    window.open(d.url, 'popUpWindow','height=600,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

And this is the json info:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Agglomerative Cluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "Community Structure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "Hierarchical Cluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "Merge Edge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Betweenness Centrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "Link Distance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "Max Flow Min Cut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "Shortest Paths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "Spanning Tree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Aspect Ratio Banker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

I would like to be able to decide, for example, to break Aspect / Ratio Banker or Aspect Ratio / Banker.

Comment: You have to insert the line breaks yourself. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts).

Comment: @ViviD, one question, I noted that the following portion of code:

nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")

... might be affecting the position of the text in relation with the circles, Is there a way to place the first line closely to the center in a relatively easy way?

Comment: Experiment with dy, thats it. Also, you can center the text horizontally, see svg documentation.

Comment: You can play with dx too. If you set dx to be radius of the circle, the whole text will appear outside of the circle, just beside it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/2j9Ls/1/) solves your problem.

The code is actually your example, just a little bit modified.

There is a new function wordwrap2() that takes care of proper splitting of the names:

```
function wordwrap2( str, width, brk, cut ) {
    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;
    if (!str) { return str; }
    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');
    return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
}
```

Then, there is a new important part of the code that, instead of just creating one text label per node, creates this:

```
  var maxLength = 20;
  var separation = 18;
  var textX = 0;
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")
      .each(function (d) {
          var lines = wordwrap2(d.name, maxLength).split('\n');
          console.log(d.name);
          console.log(lines);
          for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
              d3.select(this)
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("dy", separation)
                .attr("x", textX)
                .text(lines[i]);
           }
    });
```

(variable maxLength - length used for criterium for splitting names)

(variable separation - visual vertical distance between split lines of a name)

For example this would be the output for maxLength=20:

[image: maxLength=20]

This would be the output for maxLength=15: (notice that Aspect Ratio Banker became Aspect Ratio/Banker)

[image: maxLength=15]

This would be the output for maxLength=10: (now, check out Aspect/Ratio/Banker !)

[image: maxLength=10]

And this would be the output for maxLength=10 and separation=30 (a little more space between individual lines):

[image: maxLength=10 separation=30]

Comment: Of course, you can remove lines with console.log() that I used for debugging... :)

Comment: Awesome solution. Is there a way to set the y attribute? Because my tspans  inside my rects are a bit too low for my liking. If i select all tspan and set the y every t span is in the same location. How do I set to be d.y for the 1st tspan only then just regular new lines after that?