# XAxis label problems

Tags: d3.js, label, bar-chart

Good afternoon.

I ask you how to solve the problem with xAxis labels when the data is huge (overlapping layers) and you indicate me the insertion of a new lines (*), althought I have a probleme in my slipt function.

Someone have a soggestion for this problem.

- [How do I include newlines in labels in D3 charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts)

My chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/tL2hW/

Solution:

```
var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
  var el = d3.select(this);
  var words = d.split(' ');
  el.text('');

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
    if (i > 0)
        tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
  }
};

svg.selectAll('g.x.axis g text').each(insertLinebreaks);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this solution: 
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

Rotating the labels of the x-axis works until you have a way too large amount of bars. If the number of bars is too high I would suggest re-thinking the table since it will not be easy for anyone to see. There are guidelines to this if you google information visualization.

To have a general label for the unit of the axis rotated to be horizontal, use

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-XX)")
```

on the specific text element XX degrees.

Comment: Thanks this solution fit perfectly with my problem. I only have a doubt, how I can insert the xAxis name with this tipology.
With the normal xAxis I use this:
.append("text")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("dy", 30)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Generation");
But  with totate lablesit does not work.

Comment: You can use .attr("transform", "rotate(-XX)") to rotate each text element XX degrees. So do what you do and add the transform rotate and you should be all set!