# Javascript text on a newline D3 Viz?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a collapsable tree and have the role below the name. I tried adding in `<br>` and new line character but its not working.  Right now it's just Name : Role and I want Role under name?

```
 nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
       //HERE
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + ": " + d.role})
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts