# How To Align Text Inside SVG In D3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

I created a visual data with bar chart but I'm having trouble aligning the text "Gross Domestic Product" and "Units: Billions of Dollars Seasonal Adjustment: Seasonally Adjusted, Annual Rate Notes: A Guide to the National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA) - (http://www.bea.gov/national/pdf/nipaguid.pdf)"

As of now they are over lapping at the top:
[image]

I want to align "Gross Domestic Product" at the top and "Units: Billions of Dollars Seasonal Adjustment: Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate Notes: A Guide to the National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA) - (http://www.bea.gov/national/pdf/nipaguid.pdf)" at the bottom like 
[image]

[Here Is My Code Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cannelflow/nuwzxoz8/)

```js
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

//Fetch Data By .$getJSON Method
$.getJSON(url, function (d) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
    var data = d.data;
    /*test data by
    console.log(data[0][0]);
    */
    //create Margin
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    /*
       Define Min & Max Data for Scale
    */
    console.log(d.description);
    var minDate = new Date(data[0][0]);
    var maxDate = new Date(data[d.data.length - 1][0]);
    /*
     test data by 
     console.log(minDate);
     console.log(maxDate);
    */
    /*
    define scale then followed by axis
    */
    // define x and y scales
    // define x and y scales
    var xScale = d3.time.scale().
        domain([minDate, maxDate]).
        range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().
        domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d[1];
        })]).
        range([height, 0]);
    // define x axis and y axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(xScale).
        orient("bottom").
        ticks(d3.time.years, 5);
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(yScale).
        orient("left").
        ticks(10, "");
    var thisDate = new Date(data[0][0]);
    /*
    Create Tooltip
    */
    var toolTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return ('<strong>$' + d[1].toLocaleString() + ' Billion</strong><p>' + thisDate.getFullYear() + ' - ' + monthNames[thisDate.getMonth()] + '</p>');
      });
    /*
    create svg element then append height and width and g which act as a container
    */
    var svg = d3.select(".mainContainer").
      attr({
          "width": width + margin.right + margin.left,
          "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom
      }).
    append("g").
      attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");

    //call toolTip
    svg.call(toolTip);
    // Draw xAxis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
    //Draw yAxis
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
   .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Gross Domestic Product, USA");
    /*
  create bar or bind data
  */
    //bind data
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
   //enter data
    .enter().
        append("rect")
   //update data
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(new Date(d[0])); })
      .attr("width", Math.ceil(width / data.length))
      .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yScale(d[1]); })
      .on('mouseover', toolTip.show)
      .on('mouseout', toolTip.hide);
    //add description on top and bottom of svg
    svg.
        attr("class", "title").
        append("text").
        html("Gross Domestic Product </br>")
    svg.
        attr("class", "notes").
        append("text").
        text(d.description);
    

});
```

```css
svg {
  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
}
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.notes {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: steelblue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
.title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: steelblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3-Zipline: GDP Bar Graph</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.6.7/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <br /><br />
        <svg class="mainContainer">
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to address here:

1. Create an x-axis label that is properly aligned
2. Split the long x-axis label over multiple lines (it's too long otherwise)
3. Set the CSS classes correctly for the title, notes, and other text elements

Taking them in that order:

**X-axis label under the axis, centered**

The simplest way to do this is to append your text between the code where you draw the x-axis and the y-axis.

```
svg.append("text")    // text label for the x axis
  .attr("class", "notes")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ")")
  .attr("y",  height + margin.bottom)
  .text(d.description)
  .call(splitLongLabel);    // The next section explains this bit...
```

**Split the long x-axis label over multiple lines**

To do this, I've borrowed a little from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275930/3442309

It looks like the most sensible place to split the `d.description` text is at the "-" character: This is how it's done on the screenshot of how you want the chart to look.

To achieve the split, user `tspan` elements

```
var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
    var el = d;    // Get the current element
    var words = d.text().split("-");    // Split text  at the hyphen
    el.text('');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {    // Then build up the tspans
        var tspan = el.append('tspan')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .text(words[i])
            .style("text-anchor", "middle");
        if (i > 0)
            tspan
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('dy', '15')
                .style("text-anchor", "middle");
    }
};
```

To change how and where this label is split, or to make it more generic (eg basing the split on length, rather than a specific character), simply modify how `split` is defined

**Setting CSS classes for text**

In your example, the title was not using the `title` CSS class, so not getting the expected style. The reason for this is the following code at the end of your script:

```
svg.
    attr("class", "notes").
    append("text").
    text(d.description);
```

What this was doing was setting the `notes` style for *all* text in the svg. More correctly, you should have set the class attribute *after* appending the text.

Correcting for this, for the title, we now have:

```
svg.
    //attr("class", "title"). <- Removed from here
    append("text").
    attr("class", "title").    // <- added here
    html("Gross Domestic Product </br>")
```

and I've added some positioning to the javascript for `title, rather than in the CSS:

```
    ....
    .attr('x', width / 2)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Lastly, I've corrected your CSS, which used `color` for applying text color, instead of `fill`, which is the correct way

Here's a Fiddle with all the changes described: https://jsfiddle.net/henbox/nuwzxoz8/1/

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i wanted i just noticed another problem if you see tool tip date part is constant to 1947 January can you help me fixing this thank again

Comment: You just need to change where you set `thisdate`, to be inside the `toolTip` function (to ensure that it is re-initialised every time you hover on a new bar). I've made the change here: https://jsfiddle.net/henbox/nuwzxoz8/2/