# How can i insert a value "inside" a picture in html/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, indexing

How can i insert a value "inside" a picture in html/jquery??
I currently have a GTA server, and i wanted to add something similar as the picture below shows, a clothing shop with numbers in each picture.

[image: example]

I have the main script all done(the clothing shop), but i want to insert a number in each picture, so that it can get easier for the player to find the respective clothing.
Being more precise, i wanted to insert the 'data-action' value "inside" the picture.
Here is a piece of the html, so it can get easier to understand.

[image: html]

I've been researching for two days straight, found nothing.. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about this all wrong. You can't put anything ***inside*** an image. You can put html on top of an image element though or use the image as background for some html

Comment: Agreed, that's why i said "inside". Do you have any idea how can i do that? Put the HTML on top of an image? Thanks.

Comment: Open the page you took screenshot of and inspect their html in your browser dev tools element inspector. Will see how they did it

Comment: Should be easy to find lots of tutorials for content over an image. Suspect you have been trying to search incorrectly for content inside image. Simplest is using wrapping parent container and another div inside it that is position absolute to put other content inside

Comment: Also inspecting the existing example in browser dev tools will give you a lot of insight

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! How do i close the topic?

Comment: Not sure what exactly worked but glad you got the basics sorted out

Comment: This: "Suspect you have been trying to search incorrectly for content inside image."
Thanks, even though you didn't gave me the solution for it, you gave me the right tool to find.

Comment: Ahh but isn't it better to teach a man to fish than to just give him a fish? Learning the tools and how to debug is just as critical as learning how to create the code also

Answer (score 0):

Check out SVG (Scalable Vector Graphic): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element

You can load the picture as the background and then write whatever you want over it very easily using the `<text>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

You can also do it using D3.js as described here: [How to center a text on a svg image using d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525192/how-to-center-a-text-on-a-svg-image-using-d3-js)

Also, everything in the SVG is an HTML element with the normal events—onclick, etc. So you can make them reactive.

**Updated**

The simplest way would be to use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). Here is an example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

It uses a `<div>` element, but you could just use the same CSS on the `<button>` instead, if you want.

Comment: Using `d3.js` to simply center a text in an SVG is definitely an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML5 "canvas".  Put the image in the canvas as a "background".  Then use canvas tools to draw lines, write text, make circles, etc.

That uses x & y coordinates for placement; getting the right values for those will be the challenge.