# D3 chart: While using d3.axisLeft(y) method, how do I prevent Y-Axis grid-lines from using the entire chart width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First of all, I apologize for such a long post and my absolute beginner knowledge about D3 framework.

I have managed to draw the following chart using D3 framework.

[image]

However, I am not been able to accomplish the following things:

1) Cannot draw Y-Axis vertical sideline
2) Cannot make the Y-Axis ticks to align centered. At the moment they all are left-aligned
3) Cannot make the color of X-Axis baseline same as Y-Axis gridlines
4) Cannot make the label "Growth Target (7)" center-aligned Right now it is left-aligned

**1) Y-Axis Vertical Sideline:**
The text **Growth Target (7)** is within the chart. In order to make the gridlines to stop before this, I have used this (***approach 1***)

```
// ******************* << Custom Y axis grid lines Begins
var yGrid = svg.selectAll(".hgrid")
  .data(yTicks)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d){
      return "translate(0, " + y(d) + ")"
  });

yGrid.append("line")
  .attr("class", "hgrid")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  // shorten growth target line width to give room for the label
  .attr("x2", width - growth_target_width_adjusted);

yGrid.append("text")
  .text(function(d){return d; })
  .attr("class", "hgrid-label")
  // update X and Y positions of the label
  .attr("x", -15)
  .attr("y", "0.3em");

d3.selectAll(".hgrid-label")
  .each(function (d, i) {
      d3.select(this).style("font-size", 13);
});

// ******************* Custom Y axis grid lines Ends >>
```

Rather than this (***approach 2***):

```
// gridlines in y axis function
function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y)
      .tickValues(yTicks);
}

// add the Y grid lines
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid axis yAxis")
  .call(draw_yAxis_gridlines()
     .tickSize(-width)
);
```

The above ***approach 2***, however, creates the Y-Axis baseline but the gridlines are using the entire chart area and overlapping the text "Growth Target (7)".

Is there any way that I can control the width of each Y-Axis line using ***approach 2***? If not, how can I draw the Y-Axis baseline using ***approach 1***?

**2) Y-Axis ticks to align center**
Currently, the Y-Axis tick values (0, 5, 10...) are left-aligned. Is there a way to make them centered?

**3) Color of X-Axis baseline same as Y-Axis gridlines**
In my chart above, the X-Axis color is black while the gridline colors are light gray. I need to make the X-Axis color light gray as well. What is the right way to do this?

**4) Center aligning the label "Growth Target (7)"**
What is the right way to make the two lines of the label centered-aligned? Right now the lines are aligned left to each other.

The desired output needs to be like this:

[image]

Here is the complete chart script that I have now:

```
function barColor(data_month, current_month) {
    if( parseInt(data_month) >= current_month)
        return "#008600";
    else
        return "#c4c4c4";
}

function draw_gp_chart(data_str) {

    var chart_container = jQuery("#ecbg_unitary");
    jQuery(chart_container).html("");

    var w = parseInt(jQuery(chart_container).width());
    var h = 375;
    var barPadding = 2;

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var growth_target_width_adjusted = margin.left + margin.right;

    var svg = d3.select("#ecbg_unitary")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", 10)");

    var data = data_str;

    // set the ranges (less width of chart to allow room for Growth Target label)
    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width - growth_target_width_adjusted]).padding(0.2);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


    // Scale the range of the data in the domains
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.month;
    }));

    var y_domain_upperBound = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.points;
    });
    y_domain_upperBound = Math.round(y_domain_upperBound / 10) * 10 + 10;
    y.domain([0, y_domain_upperBound]);

    // Create Y-Axis tick array to draw grid lines
    var yTicks = [];
    var tickInterval = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i <= y_domain_upperBound; i = i + tickInterval) {
        yTicks.push(i);
    }

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues(yTicks);
    }

    // ******************* << Growth Target line Begins
    var targetGoalArr = [parseInt(jQuery("#ecbg_unitary_growth_target").val())];

    var target = svg.selectAll(".targetgoal")
        .data(targetGoalArr)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            return "translate(0, " + y(d) + ")"
        });

    target.append("line")
        .attr("class", "targetgoal")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        // shorten growth target line width to give room for the label
        .attr("x2", width - growth_target_width_adjusted);

    // Adding two SVG text elements since SVG text element does not support text-wrapping.
    // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13254862/1496518
    // Option 2: may be tried later - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

    // Text element 1
    target.append("text")
        .text(function(d){return "Growth " })
        .attr("class", "tglebal")
        // update X position of the label
        .attr("x", width - growth_target_width_adjusted + 5)
        .attr("y", "-0.3em");

    // Text element 2
    target.append("text")
        .text(function(d){return "Target (" + d + ")" })
        .attr("class", "tglebal")
        // update X position of the label
        .attr("x", width - growth_target_width_adjusted + 5)
        .attr("y", "1em");

    d3.selectAll(".tglebal")
        .each(function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("font-size", 12);
        });

    // ******************* Growth Target line Ends >>

    // ******************* << Custom Y axis grid lines Begins
    var yGrid = svg.selectAll(".hgrid")
        .data(yTicks)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            return "translate(0, " + y(d) + ")"
        });

    yGrid.append("line")
        .attr("class", "hgrid")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        // shorten growth target line width to give room for the label
        .attr("x2", width - growth_target_width_adjusted);

    yGrid.append("text")
        .text(function(d){return d; })
        .attr("class", "hgrid-label")
        // update X and Y positions of the label
        .attr("x", -15)
        .attr("y", "0.3em");

    d3.selectAll(".hgrid-label")
        .each(function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("font-size", 13);
        });

    // ******************* Custom Y axis grid lines Ends >>

    // append the rectangles for the bar chart
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.month);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.points);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.points);
        })
        //.attr("height", function(d) {return d.points;})
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return barColor(d.data_month_number, d.current_month_number)
        });


    // column labels
    svg.selectAll(".colvalue")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "colvalue")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.points;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return x(d.month) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
        })
        //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            //return h - (d.points * 4) - 10;
            return y(d.points) - 10;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "Roboto")
        .attr("font-size", "13px")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("fill", "#606668");

    // add the x Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // text label (axis name) for the x axis
    var xAxisNameHeightFromTop = height + margin.bottom + 20;

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis-name")
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ", " + xAxisNameHeightFromTop + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("MONTH");

    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis-name")
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("SALES UNITS");

    // add the Y grid lines
    /*svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid axis yAxis")
        .call(draw_yAxis_gridlines()
            .tickSize(-width)
        );*/

    d3.selectAll(".yAxis>.tick>text")
        .each(function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("font-size", 13);
        });
}
```