# D3 js: I want to know how to make a horizontal line according to the y-axis value

Tags: d3.js

link : [D3 Charting Tool: How to add label at right of target line (additional horizontal line) in column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082594/d3-charting-tool-how-to-add-label-at-right-of-target-line-additional-horizonta)

I implemented the graph through this link.
The problem is that if there are multiple graphs and the y-axis values are different at the same height, if the horizon value is 10px, then 10px is output regardless of the y-axis range.
If i want to add horizontal lines according to the y-axis range, I'd like to know a solution.