# "Mouseup" event not fired after migrating from D3 v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and I am trying to use this [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459)
It uses v3 and I am trying to migrate it to v5.16.0

What I could do is change `d3.behavior.drag()`, `.origin` and `.on("dragend"`
into
`d3.drag()`, `.subject` and `.on("end",`

and change this `.on("zoomstart"` and this `.on("zoomend"` into this `.on("start"` and this `.on("end"`

I am not getting any runtime errors but there is a malfunction. For example I can't mouse click + "shift" to create a new node like in the demo and also when a node is clicked its color doesn't change and also when I drag a node I get this messy behaviour as shown in this image
[image]

I could figure out that for some reason the on `mouseup` event is not fired but I coudn't figure out the reason.

Can someone please help?

New Full code I am using:

```
document.onload = (function(d3, saveAs, Blob, undefined){
  "use strict";

  // define graphcreator object
  var GraphCreator = function(svg, nodes, edges){
    var thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.idct = 0;
    
    thisGraph.nodes = nodes || [];
    thisGraph.edges = edges || [];
    
    thisGraph.state = {
      selectedNode: null,
      selectedEdge: null,
      mouseDownNode: null,
      mouseDownLink: null,
      justDragged: false,
      justScaleTransGraph: false,
      lastKeyDown: -1,
      shiftNodeDrag: false,
      selectedText: null
    };

    // define arrow markers for graph links
    var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
    defs.append('svg:marker')
      .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
      .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
      .attr('refX', "32")
      .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
      .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

    // define arrow markers for leading arrow
    defs.append('svg:marker')
      .attr('id', 'mark-end-arrow')
      .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
      .attr('refX', 7)
      .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
      .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

    thisGraph.svg = svg;
    thisGraph.svgG = svg.append("g")
          .classed(thisGraph.consts.graphClass, true);
    var svgG = thisGraph.svgG;

    // displayed when dragging between nodes
    thisGraph.dragLine = svgG.append('svg:path')
          .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
          .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0')
          .style('marker-end', 'url(#mark-end-arrow)');

    // svg nodes and edges 
    thisGraph.paths = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");
    thisGraph.circles = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");

    thisGraph.drag = d3.drag()
          .subject(function(d){
            return {x: d.x, y: d.y};
          })
          .on("drag", function(args){
            thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;
            thisGraph.dragmove.call(thisGraph, args);
          })
          .on("end", function() {
            // todo check if edge-mode is selected
          });

    // listen for key events
    d3.select(window).on("keydown", function(){
      thisGraph.svgKeyDown.call(thisGraph);
    })
    .on("keyup", function(){
      thisGraph.svgKeyUp.call(thisGraph);
    });
    svg.on("mousedown", function(d){thisGraph.svgMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d);});
    svg.on("mouseup", function(d){thisGraph.svgMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d);});

    // listen for dragging
    var dragSvg = d3.zoom()
          .on("zoom", function(){
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey){
              // TODO  the internal d3 state is still changing
              return false;
            } else{
              thisGraph.zoomed.call(thisGraph);
            }
            return true;
          })
          .on("start", function(){
            var ael = d3.select("#" + thisGraph.consts.activeEditId).node();
            if (ael){
              ael.blur();
            }
            if (!d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) d3.select('body').style("cursor", "move");
          })
          .on("end", function(){
            d3.select('body').style("cursor", "auto");
          });
    
    svg.call(dragSvg).on("dblclick.zoom", null);

    // listen for resize
    window.onresize = function(){thisGraph.updateWindow(svg);};

    // handle download data
    d3.select("#download-input").on("click", function(){
      var saveEdges = [];
      thisGraph.edges.forEach(function(val, i){
        saveEdges.push({source: val.source.id, target: val.target.id});
      });
      var blob = new Blob([window.JSON.stringify({"nodes": thisGraph.nodes, "edges": saveEdges})], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
      saveAs(blob, "mydag.json");
    });


    // handle uploaded data
    d3.select("#upload-input").on("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("hidden-file-upload").click();
    });
    d3.select("#hidden-file-upload").on("change", function(){
      if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var uploadFile = this.files[0];
        var filereader = new window.FileReader();
        
        filereader.onload = function(){
          var txtRes = filereader.result;
          // TODO better error handling
          try{
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(txtRes);
            thisGraph.deleteGraph(true);
            thisGraph.nodes = jsonObj.nodes;
            thisGraph.setIdCt(jsonObj.nodes.length + 1);
            var newEdges = jsonObj.edges;
            newEdges.forEach(function(e, i){
              newEdges[i] = {source: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function(n){return n.id == e.source;})[0],
                          target: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function(n){return n.id == e.target;})[0]};
            });
            thisGraph.edges = newEdges;
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
          }catch(err){
            window.alert("Error parsing uploaded file\nerror message: " + err.message);
            return;
          }
        };
        filereader.readAsText(uploadFile);
        
      } else {
        alert("Your browser won't let you save this graph -- try upgrading your browser to IE 10+ or Chrome or Firefox.");
      }

    });

    // handle delete graph
    d3.select("#delete-graph").on("click", function(){
      thisGraph.deleteGraph(false);
    });
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.setIdCt = function(idct){
    this.idct = idct;
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.consts =  {
    selectedClass: "selected",
    connectClass: "connect-node",
    circleGClass: "conceptG",
    graphClass: "graph",
    activeEditId: "active-editing",
    BACKSPACE_KEY: 8,
    DELETE_KEY: 46,
    ENTER_KEY: 13,
    nodeRadius: 50
  };

  /* PROTOTYPE FUNCTIONS */

  GraphCreator.prototype.dragmove = function(d) {
    var thisGraph = this;
    if (thisGraph.state.shiftNodeDrag){
      thisGraph.dragLine.attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node())[0] + ',' + d3.mouse(this.svgG.node())[1]);
    } else{
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y +=  d3.event.dy;
      thisGraph.updateGraph();
    }
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.deleteGraph = function(skipPrompt){
    var thisGraph = this,
        doDelete = true;
    if (!skipPrompt){
      doDelete = window.confirm("Press OK to delete this graph");
    }
    if(doDelete){
      thisGraph.nodes = [];
      thisGraph.edges = [];
      thisGraph.updateGraph();
    }
  };

  /* select all text in element: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element */
  GraphCreator.prototype.selectElementContents = function(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  };


  /* insert svg line breaks: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts */
  GraphCreator.prototype.insertTitleLinebreaks = function (gEl, title) {
    var words = title.split(/\s+/g),
        nwords = words.length;
    var el = gEl.append("text")
          .attr("text-anchor","middle")
          .attr("dy", "-" + (nwords-1)*7.5);

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
      if (i > 0)
        tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
    }
  };

  
  // remove edges associated with a node
  GraphCreator.prototype.spliceLinksForNode = function(node) {
    var thisGraph = this,
        toSplice = thisGraph.edges.filter(function(l) {
      return (l.source === node || l.target === node);
    });
    toSplice.map(function(l) {
      thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(l), 1);
    });
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectEdge = function(d3Path, edgeData){
    var thisGraph = this;
    d3Path.classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, true);
    if (thisGraph.state.selectedEdge){
      thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
    }
    thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = edgeData;
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectNode = function(d3Node, nodeData){
    var thisGraph = this;
    d3Node.classed(this.consts.selectedClass, true);
    if (thisGraph.state.selectedNode){
      thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
    }
    thisGraph.state.selectedNode = nodeData;
  };
  
  GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromNode = function(){
    var thisGraph = this;
    thisGraph.circles.filter(function(cd){
      return cd.id === thisGraph.state.selectedNode.id;
    }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
    thisGraph.state.selectedNode = null;
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromEdge = function(){
    var thisGraph = this;
    thisGraph.paths.filter(function(cd){
      return cd === thisGraph.state.selectedEdge;
    }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
    thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = null;
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.pathMouseDown = function(d3path, d){
    var thisGraph = this,
        state = thisGraph.state;
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    state.mouseDownLink = d;

    if (state.selectedNode){
      thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
    }
    
    var prevEdge = state.selectedEdge;  
    if (!prevEdge || prevEdge !== d){
      thisGraph.replaceSelectEdge(d3path, d);
    } else{
      thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
    }
  };

  // mousedown on node
  GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseDown = function(d3node, d){
    var thisGraph = this,
        state = thisGraph.state;
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    state.mouseDownNode = d;
    if (d3.event.shiftKey){
      state.shiftNodeDrag = d3.event.shiftKey;
      // reposition dragged directed edge
      thisGraph.dragLine.classed('hidden', false)
        .attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d.x + ',' + d.y);
      return;
    }
  };

  /* place editable text on node in place of svg text */
  GraphCreator.prototype.changeTextOfNode = function(d3node, d){
    var thisGraph= this,
        consts = thisGraph.consts,
        htmlEl = d3node.node();
    d3node.selectAll("text").remove();
    var nodeBCR = htmlEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
        curScale = nodeBCR.width/consts.nodeRadius,
        placePad  =  5*curScale,
        useHW = curScale > 1 ? nodeBCR.width*0.71 : consts.nodeRadius*1.42;
    // replace with editableconent text
    var d3txt = thisGraph.svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
          .data([d])
          .enter()
          .append("foreignObject")
          .attr("x", nodeBCR.left + placePad )
          .attr("y", nodeBCR.top + placePad)
          .attr("height", 2*useHW)
          .attr("width", useHW)
          .append("xhtml:p")
          .attr("id", consts.activeEditId)
          .attr("contentEditable", "true")
          .text(d.title)
          .on("mousedown", function(d){
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
          })
          .on("keydown", function(d){
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
            if (d3.event.keyCode == consts.ENTER_KEY && !d3.event.shiftKey){
              this.blur();
            }
          })
          .on("blur", function(d){
            d.title = this.textContent;
            thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3node, d.title);
            d3.select(this.parentElement).remove();
          });
    return d3txt;
  };

  // mouseup on nodes
  GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseUp = function(d3node, d){
    var thisGraph = this,
        state = thisGraph.state,
        consts = thisGraph.consts;
    // reset the states
    state.shiftNodeDrag = false;    
    d3node.classed(consts.connectClass, false);
    
    var mouseDownNode = state.mouseDownNode;
    
    if (!mouseDownNode) return;

    thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);

    if (mouseDownNode !== d){
      // we're in a different node: create new edge for mousedown edge and add to graph
      var newEdge = {source: mouseDownNode, target: d};
      var filtRes = thisGraph.paths.filter(function(d){
        if (d.source === newEdge.target && d.target === newEdge.source){
          thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(d), 1);
        }
        return d.source === newEdge.source && d.target === newEdge.target;
      });
      if (!filtRes[0].length){
        thisGraph.edges.push(newEdge);
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
      }
    } else{
      // we're in the same node
      if (state.justDragged) {
        // dragged, not clicked
        state.justDragged = false;
      } else{
        // clicked, not dragged
        if (d3.event.shiftKey){
          // shift-clicked node: edit text content
          var d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(d3node, d);
          var txtNode = d3txt.node();
          thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
          txtNode.focus();
        } else{
          if (state.selectedEdge){
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
          }
          var prevNode = state.selectedNode;            
          
          if (!prevNode || prevNode.id !== d.id){
            thisGraph.replaceSelectNode(d3node, d);
          } else{
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    state.mouseDownNode = null;
    return;
    
  }; // end of circles mouseup

  // mousedown on main svg
  GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseDown = function(){
    this.state.graphMouseDown = true;
  };

  // mouseup on main svg
  GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseUp = function(){
    var thisGraph = this,
        state = thisGraph.state;
    if (state.justScaleTransGraph) {
      // dragged not clicked
      state.justScaleTransGraph = false;
    } else if (state.graphMouseDown && d3.event.shiftKey){
      // clicked not dragged from svg
      var xycoords = d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node()),
          d = {id: thisGraph.idct++, title: "new concept", x: xycoords[0], y: xycoords[1]};
      thisGraph.nodes.push(d);
      thisGraph.updateGraph();
      // make title of text immediently editable
      var d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(thisGraph.circles.filter(function(dval){
        return dval.id === d.id;
      }), d),
          txtNode = d3txt.node();
      thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
      txtNode.focus();
    } else if (state.shiftNodeDrag){
      // dragged from node
      state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
      thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);
    }
    state.graphMouseDown = false;
  };

  // keydown on main svg
  GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyDown = function() {
    var thisGraph = this,
        state = thisGraph.state,
        consts = thisGraph.consts;
    // make sure repeated key presses don't register for each keydown
    if(state.lastKeyDown !== -1) return;

    state.lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;
    var selectedNode = state.selectedNode,
        selectedEdge = state.selectedEdge;

    switch(d3.event.keyCode) {
    case consts.BACKSPACE_KEY:
    case consts.DELETE_KEY:
      d3.event.preventDefault();
      if (selectedNode){
        thisGraph.nodes.splice(thisGraph.nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
        thisGraph.spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
        state.selectedNode = null;
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
      } else if (selectedEdge){
        thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(selectedEdge), 1);
        state.selectedEdge = null;
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
      }
      break;
    }
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyUp = function() {
    this.state.lastKeyDown = -1;
  };

  // call to propagate changes to graph
  GraphCreator.prototype.updateGraph = function(){
    
    var thisGraph = this,
        consts = thisGraph.consts,
        state = thisGraph.state;
    thisGraph.paths = thisGraph.paths.data(thisGraph.edges, function(d){
      return String(d.source.id) + "+" + String(d.target.id);
    });
    var paths = thisGraph.paths;
    // update existing paths
    paths.style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
      .classed(consts.selectedClass, function(d){
        return d === state.selectedEdge;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d){
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      });

    // add new paths
    paths.enter()
      .append("path")
      .style('marker-end','url(#end-arrow)')
      .classed("link", true)
      .attr("d", function(d){
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      })
      .on("mousedown", function(d){
        thisGraph.pathMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
        }
      )
      .on("mouseup", function(d){
        state.mouseDownLink = null;
      });

    // remove old links
    paths.exit().remove();
    
    // update existing nodes
    thisGraph.circles = thisGraph.circles.data(thisGraph.nodes, function(d){ return d.id;});
    thisGraph.circles.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});

    // add new nodes
    var newGs= thisGraph.circles.enter()
          .append("g");
    newGs.classed(consts.circleGClass, true)
      .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
      .on("mouseover", function(d){        
        if (state.shiftNodeDrag){
          d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, true);
        }
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, false);
      })
      .on("mousedown", function(d){
        thisGraph.circleMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
      })
      .on("mouseup", function(d){
        thisGraph.circleMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
      })
      .call(thisGraph.drag);

    newGs.append("circle")
      .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));

    newGs.each(function(d){
      thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3.select(this), d.title);
    });

    // remove old nodes
    thisGraph.circles.exit().remove();
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.zoomed = function(){
    this.state.justScaleTransGraph = true;
    d3.select("." + this.consts.graphClass)
      .attr("transform", d3.event.transform); 
  };

  GraphCreator.prototype.updateWindow = function(svg){
    var docEl = document.documentElement,
        bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var x = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth;
    var y = window.innerHeight|| docEl.clientHeight|| bodyEl.clientHeight;
    svg.attr("width", x).attr("height", y);
  };


  
  /**** MAIN ****/

  // warn the user when leaving
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Make sure to save your graph locally before leaving :-)";
  };      

  var docEl = document.documentElement,
      bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  
  var width = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth,
      height =  window.innerHeight|| docEl.clientHeight|| bodyEl.clientHeight;

  var xLoc = width/2 - 25,
      yLoc = 100;

  // initial node data
  var nodes = [{title: "new concept", id: 0, x: xLoc, y: yLoc},
               {title: "new concept", id: 1, x: xLoc, y: yLoc + 200}];
  var edges = [{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[0]}];


  /** MAIN SVG **/
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
  var graph = new GraphCreator(svg, nodes, edges);
      graph.setIdCt(2);
  graph.updateGraph();
})(window.d3, window.saveAs, window.Blob);
```

[d3 v5.16.0 cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js)

Thank you so much

Comment: Could you post your attempted code?

Comment: Sure, I just edited @Jacob

Comment: Do you think maybe it's because of the `d3.event.stopPropagation();` line in the other `mousedown` handler?

Comment: @Jacob I tried to comment it out but that's not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs it, this is the solution I found:

```
document.onload = (function (d3, saveAs, Blob, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    // define graphcreator object
    let GraphCreator = function (svg, nodes, edges) {
        let thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.idct = 0;

        thisGraph.nodes = nodes || [];
        thisGraph.edges = edges || [];

        thisGraph.state = {
            selectedNode: null,
            selectedEdge: null,
            mouseDownNode: null,
            mouseEnterNode: null,
            mouseDownLink: null,
            justDragged: false,
            justScaleTransGraph: false,
            lastKeyDown: -1,
            shiftNodeDrag: false,
            selectedText: null
        };

        // define arrow markers for graph links
        let defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
        defs.append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', "32")
            .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
            .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

        // define arrow markers for leading arrow
        defs.append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'mark-end-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', 7)
            .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
            .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

        thisGraph.svg = svg;
        thisGraph.svgG = svg.append("g")
            .classed(thisGraph.consts.graphClass, true);
        let svgG = thisGraph.svgG;

        // displayed when dragging between nodes
        thisGraph.dragLine = svgG.append('svg:path')
            .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
            .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0')
            .style('marker-end', 'url(#mark-end-arrow)');

        // svg nodes and edges
        thisGraph.paths = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");
        thisGraph.circles = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");

        thisGraph.drag = d3.drag()
            .subject(function (d) {
                return {x: d.x, y: d.y};
            })
            .on("drag", function (args) {
                thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;
                thisGraph.dragmove.call(thisGraph, args);
            })
            .on("end", function (d) {
                // todo check if edge-mode is selected
                var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
                var elem = document.elementFromPoint(mouse[0], mouse[1]);
                if (thisGraph.state.shiftNodeDrag) {
                    thisGraph.dragEnd.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), thisGraph.state.mouseEnterNode)
                }

            });

        // listen for key events
        d3.select(window).on("keydown", function () {
            thisGraph.svgKeyDown.call(thisGraph);
        })
            .on("keyup", function () {
                thisGraph.svgKeyUp.call(thisGraph);
            });
        svg.on("mousedown", function (d) {
            thisGraph.svgMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d);
            if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
                d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
        svg.on("mouseup", function (d) {
            thisGraph.svgMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d);
        });

        // listen for dragging
        let dragSvg = d3.zoom()
            .on("zoom", function () {
                if (d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) {
                    // TODO  the internal d3 state is still changing
                    return false;
                } else {
                    thisGraph.zoomed.call(thisGraph);
                }
                return true;
            })
            .on("start", function () {
                var ael = d3.select("#" + thisGraph.consts.activeEditId).node();
                if (ael) {
                    ael.blur();
                }
                if (!d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) d3.select('body').style("cursor", "move");
            })
            .on("end", function () {
                d3.select('body').style("cursor", "auto");
            });

        svg.call(dragSvg).on("dblclick.zoom", null);

        // listen for resize
        window.onresize = function () {
            thisGraph.updateWindow(svg);
        };

        // handle download data
        d3.select("#download-input").on("click", function () {
            let saveEdges = [];
            thisGraph.edges.forEach(function (val, i) {
                saveEdges.push({source: val.source.id, target: val.target.id});
            });
            let blob = new Blob([window.JSON.stringify({
                "nodes": thisGraph.nodes,
                "edges": saveEdges
            })], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, "mydag.json");
        });


        // handle uploaded data
        d3.select("#upload-input").on("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("hidden-file-upload").click();
        });
        d3.select("#hidden-file-upload").on("change", function () {
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                let uploadFile = this.files[0];
                let filereader = new window.FileReader();

                filereader.onload = function () {
                    let txtRes = filereader.result;
                    // TODO better error handling
                    try {
                        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(txtRes);
                        thisGraph.deleteGraph(true);
                        thisGraph.nodes = jsonObj.nodes;
                        thisGraph.setIdCt(jsonObj.nodes.length + 1);
                        let newEdges = jsonObj.edges;
                        newEdges.forEach(function (e, i) {
                            newEdges[i] = {
                                source: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function (n) {
                                    return n.id === e.source;
                                })[0],
                                target: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function (n) {
                                    return n.id === e.target;
                                })[0]
                            };
                        });
                        thisGraph.edges = newEdges;
                        thisGraph.updateGraph();
                    } catch (err) {
                        window.alert("Error parsing uploaded file\nerror message: " + err.message);
                        return;
                    }
                };
                filereader.readAsText(uploadFile);

            } else {
                alert("Your browser won't let you save this graph -- try upgrading your browser to IE 10+ or Chrome or Firefox.");
            }

        });

        // handle delete graph
        d3.select("#delete-graph").on("click", function () {
            thisGraph.deleteGraph(false);
        });
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.setIdCt = function (idct) {
        this.idct = idct;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.consts = {
        selectedClass: "selected",
        connectClass: "connect-node",
        circleGClass: "conceptG",
        graphClass: "graph",
        activeEditId: "active-editing",
        BACKSPACE_KEY: 8,
        DELETE_KEY: 46,
        ENTER_KEY: 13,
        nodeRadius: 50
    };

    /* PROTOTYPE FUNCTIONS */

    GraphCreator.prototype.dragmove = function (d) {
        let thisGraph = this;
        if (thisGraph.state.shiftNodeDrag) {
            thisGraph.dragLine.attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node())[0] + ',' + d3.mouse(this.svgG.node())[1]);
        } else {
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.deleteGraph = function (skipPrompt) {
        let thisGraph = this,
            doDelete = true;
        if (!skipPrompt) {
            doDelete = window.confirm("Press OK to delete this graph");
        }
        if (doDelete) {
            thisGraph.nodes = [];
            thisGraph.edges = [];
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
    };

    /* select all text in element: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element */
    GraphCreator.prototype.selectElementContents = function (el) {
        let range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    };


    /* insert svg line breaks: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts */
    GraphCreator.prototype.insertTitleLinebreaks = function (gEl, title) {
        let words = title.split(/\s+/g),
            nwords = words.length;
        let el = gEl.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", "-" + (nwords - 1) * 7.5);

        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            let tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
            if (i > 0)
                tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
        }
    };


    // remove edges associated with a node
    GraphCreator.prototype.spliceLinksForNode = function (node) {
        let thisGraph = this,
            toSplice = thisGraph.edges.filter(function (l) {
                return (l.source === node || l.target === node);
            });
        toSplice.map(function (l) {
            thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(l), 1);
        });
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectEdge = function (d3Path, edgeData) {
        let thisGraph = this;
        d3Path.classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, true);
        if (thisGraph.state.selectedEdge) {
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
        }
        thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = edgeData;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectNode = function (d3Node, nodeData) {
        let thisGraph = this;
        d3Node.classed(this.consts.selectedClass, true);
        if (thisGraph.state.selectedNode) {
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
        }
        thisGraph.state.selectedNode = nodeData;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromNode = function () {
        let thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.circles.filter(function (cd) {
            return cd.id === thisGraph.state.selectedNode.id;
        }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
        thisGraph.state.selectedNode = null;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromEdge = function () {
        let thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.paths.filter(function (cd) {
            return cd === thisGraph.state.selectedEdge;
        }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
        thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = null;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.pathMouseDown = function (d3path, d) {
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        state.mouseDownLink = d;

        if (state.selectedNode) {
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
        }

        let prevEdge = state.selectedEdge;
        if (!prevEdge || prevEdge !== d) {
            thisGraph.replaceSelectEdge(d3path, d);
        } else {
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
        }
    };

    // mousedown on node
    GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseDown = function (d3node, d) {
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        state.mouseDownNode = d;
        console.log(`mousedownnode = ${JSON.stringify(d)}`);
        if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
            state.shiftNodeDrag = d3.event.shiftKey;
            // reposition dragged directed edge
            thisGraph.dragLine.classed('hidden', false)
                .attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d.x + ',' + d.y);
            return;
        }
    };

    /* place editable text on node in place of svg text */
    GraphCreator.prototype.changeTextOfNode = function (d3node, d) {
        let thisGraph = this,
            consts = thisGraph.consts,
            htmlEl = d3node.node();
        d3node.selectAll("text").remove();
        let nodeBCR = htmlEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
            curScale = nodeBCR.width / consts.nodeRadius,
            placePad = 5 * curScale,
            useHW = curScale > 1 ? nodeBCR.width * 0.71 : consts.nodeRadius * 1.42;
        // replace with editableconent text
        let d3txt = thisGraph.svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
            .data([d])
            .enter()
            .append("foreignObject")
            .attr("x", nodeBCR.left + placePad)
            .attr("y", nodeBCR.top + placePad)
            .attr("height", 2 * useHW)
            .attr("width", useHW)
            .append("xhtml:p")
            .attr("id", consts.activeEditId)
            .attr("contentEditable", "true")
            .text(d.title)
            .on("mousedown", function (d) {
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on("keydown", function (d) {
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
                if (d3.event.keyCode == consts.ENTER_KEY && !d3.event.shiftKey) {
                    this.blur();
                }
            })
            .on("blur", function (d) {
                d.title = this.textContent;
                thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3node, d.title);
                d3.select(this.parentElement).remove();
            });
        return d3txt;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.dragEnd = function (d3node, d) {
        console.log('dragend');
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state,
            consts = thisGraph.consts;
        // reset the states
        state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
        d3node.classed(consts.connectClass, false);

        let mouseDownNode = state.mouseDownNode;
        let mouseEnterNode = state.mouseEnterNode;

        if (state.justDragged) {
            // dragged, not clicked
            state.justDragged = false;
        }

        thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);

        if (!mouseDownNode || !mouseEnterNode) return;


        if (mouseDownNode !== d) {
            // we're in a different node: create new edge for mousedown edge and add to graph
            let newEdge = {source: mouseDownNode, target: d};
            let filtRes = thisGraph.paths.filter(function (d) {
                if (d.source === newEdge.target && d.target === newEdge.source) {
                    thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(d), 1);
                }
                return d.source === newEdge.source && d.target === newEdge.target;
            });
            if (!filtRes || !filtRes[0] || !filtRes[0].length) {
                thisGraph.edges.push(newEdge);
                thisGraph.updateGraph();
            }
        }


        state.mouseDownNode = null;
        state.mouseEnterNode = null;
        return;
    };

    // mouseup on nodes
    GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseUp = function (d3node, d) {
        console.log('mouse up');
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state,
            consts = thisGraph.consts;
        // reset the states
        state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
        d3node.classed(consts.connectClass, false);

        if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
            // shift-clicked node: edit text content
            let d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(d3node, d);
            let txtNode = d3txt.node();
            thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
            txtNode.focus();
        } else {
            if (state.selectedEdge) {
                thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
            }
        }

        let prevNode = state.selectedNode;
        if (!prevNode || prevNode.id !== d.id) {
            thisGraph.replaceSelectNode(d3node, d);
        } else {
            thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
        }

    }; // end of circles mouseup

    // mousedown on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseDown = function () {
        this.state.graphMouseDown = true;
    };

    // mouseup on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseUp = function () {
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        if (state.justScaleTransGraph) {
            // dragged not clicked
            state.justScaleTransGraph = false;
        } else if (state.graphMouseDown && d3.event.shiftKey) {
            // clicked not dragged from svg
            let xycoords = d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node()),
                d = {id: thisGraph.idct++, title: "new concept", x: xycoords[0], y: xycoords[1]};
            thisGraph.nodes.push(d);
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
            // make title of text immediently editable
            let d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(thisGraph.circles.filter(function (dval) {
                    return dval.id === d.id;
                }), d),
                txtNode = d3txt.node();
            thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
            txtNode.focus();
        } else if (state.shiftNodeDrag) {
            // dragged from node
            state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
            thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);
        }
        state.graphMouseDown = false;
    };

    // keydown on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyDown = function () {
        let thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state,
            consts = thisGraph.consts;
        // make sure repeated key presses don't register for each keydown
        if (state.lastKeyDown !== -1) return;

        state.lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;
        let selectedNode = state.selectedNode,
            selectedEdge = state.selectedEdge;

        switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
            case consts.BACKSPACE_KEY:
            case consts.DELETE_KEY:
                d3.event.preventDefault();
                if (selectedNode) {
                    thisGraph.nodes.splice(thisGraph.nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
                    thisGraph.spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
                    state.selectedNode = null;
                    thisGraph.updateGraph();
                } else if (selectedEdge) {
                    thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(selectedEdge), 1);
                    state.selectedEdge = null;
                    thisGraph.updateGraph();
                }
                break;
        }
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyUp = function () {
        this.state.lastKeyDown = -1;
    };

    // call to propagate changes to graph
    GraphCreator.prototype.updateGraph = function () {

        let thisGraph = this,
            consts = thisGraph.consts,
            state = thisGraph.state;

        thisGraph.paths = thisGraph.paths.data(thisGraph.edges, function (d) {
            return String(d.source.id) + "+" + String(d.target.id);
        });
        let paths = thisGraph.paths;
        // update existing paths
        paths.style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
            .classed(consts.selectedClass, function (d) {
                return d === state.selectedEdge;
            })
            // .attr("d", line([d.source.x, d.source.y, d.target.x, d.target.y]));
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x  + "," + d.target.y;
            });

        // remove old links
        paths.exit().remove();

        // add new paths
        paths = paths.enter()
            .append("path")
            .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
            .classed("link", true)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x  + "," + d.target.y;
            })
            .merge(paths)
            .on("mouseup", function (d) {
                console.log('mouseup link');
                // state.mouseDownLink = null;
            })
            .on("mousedown", function (d) {
                    thisGraph.pathMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
                }
            );

        thisGraph.paths = paths;

        // update existing nodes
        thisGraph.circles = thisGraph.circles.data(thisGraph.nodes, function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });

        // remove old nodes
        thisGraph.circles.exit().remove();

        thisGraph.circles.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });


        // add new nodes
        let newGs = thisGraph.circles.enter()
            .append("g").merge(thisGraph.circles);

        newGs.classed(consts.circleGClass, true)
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            })
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                state.mouseEnterNode = d;
                if (state.shiftNodeDrag) {
                    d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, true);
                }
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                state.mouseEnterNode = null;
                d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, false);
            })
            .on("mousedown", function (d) {
                thisGraph.circleMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
            })
            .call(thisGraph.drag)
            .on("click", function (d) {
                thisGraph.circleMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
            });

        thisGraph.circles = newGs;

        newGs.each(function(d) {
          if (this.childNodes.length === 0) {
            d3.select(this)
              .append("circle")
              .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));
            thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3.select(this), d.title);
          }
        });

    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.zoomed = function () {
        this.state.justScaleTransGraph = true;
        d3.select("." + this.consts.graphClass)
            .attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.updateWindow = function (svg) {
        let docEl = document.documentElement,
            bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        let x = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth;
        let y = window.innerHeight || docEl.clientHeight || bodyEl.clientHeight;
        svg.attr("width", x).attr("height", y);
    };


    /**** MAIN ****/

    // warn the user when leaving
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Make sure to save your graph locally before leaving :-)";
    };

    let docEl = document.documentElement,
        bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    let width = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth,
        height = window.innerHeight || docEl.clientHeight || bodyEl.clientHeight;

    let xLoc = width / 2 - 25,
        yLoc = 100;

    // initial node data
    let nodes = [{title: "new concept", id: 0, x: xLoc, y: yLoc},
        {title: "new concept", id: 1, x: xLoc, y: yLoc + 200}];
    let edges = [{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[0]}];


    /** MAIN SVG **/
    let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    let graph = new GraphCreator(svg, nodes, edges);
    graph.setIdCt(2);
    graph.updateGraph();
})(window.d3, window.saveAs, window.Blob);
```

[Credits](https://github.com/ghamarian/graph_editor/blob/master/graph-creator.js)