# Using Javascript Library in Svelte Component

Tags: javascript, import, svelte

Hi Svelte Newbie here,

I came across this cool javascript library that I would like to import into my Svelte project.

https://github.com/cjrd/directed-graph-creator

However instead of having it take up a whole page like it was done originally I want to be able to have the functionality to fit into a small window within a Svelte component. As the original package was just stood up with javascript and html I don't think there should be an issue. However I'm having issues translating it into a usable svelte component. Is there an easier way to do this than done below

```
<script>

    document.onload = (function(d3, Blob, undefined){
    "use strict";

    // TODO add user settings
    var consts = {
        defaultTitle: "random variable"
    };
    var settings = {
        appendElSpec: "#graph"
    };
    // define graphcreator object
    var GraphCreator = function(svg, nodes, edges){
        var thisGraph = this;
            thisGraph.idct = 0;

        thisGraph.nodes = nodes || [];
        thisGraph.edges = edges || [];

        thisGraph.state = {
        selectedNode: null,
        selectedEdge: null,
        mouseDownNode: null,
        mouseDownLink: null,
        justDragged: false,
        justScaleTransGraph: false,
        lastKeyDown: -1,
        shiftNodeDrag: false,
        selectedText: null
        };

        // define arrow markers for graph links
        var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
        defs.append('svg:marker')
        .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
        .attr('refX', "32")
        .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
        .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
        .attr('orient', 'auto')
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

        // define arrow markers for leading arrow
        defs.append('svg:marker')
        .attr('id', 'mark-end-arrow')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
        .attr('refX', 7)
        .attr('markerWidth', 3.5)
        .attr('markerHeight', 3.5)
        .attr('orient', 'auto')
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

        thisGraph.svg = svg;
        thisGraph.svgG = svg.append("g")
            .classed(thisGraph.consts.graphClass, true);
        var svgG = thisGraph.svgG;

        // displayed when dragging between nodes
        thisGraph.dragLine = svgG.append('svg:path')
            .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
            .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0')
            .style('marker-end', 'url(#mark-end-arrow)');

        // svg nodes and edges
        thisGraph.paths = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");
        thisGraph.circles = svgG.append("g").selectAll("g");

        thisGraph.drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function(d){
                return {x: d.x, y: d.y};
            })
            .on("drag", function(args){
                thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;
                thisGraph.dragmove.call(thisGraph, args);
            })
            .on("dragend", function() {
                // todo check if edge-mode is selected
            });

        // listen for key events
        d3.select(window).on("keydown", function(){
        thisGraph.svgKeyDown.call(thisGraph);
        })
        .on("keyup", function(){
        thisGraph.svgKeyUp.call(thisGraph);
        });
        svg.on("mousedown", function(d){thisGraph.svgMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d);});
        svg.on("mouseup", function(d){thisGraph.svgMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d);});

        // listen for dragging
        var dragSvg = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on("zoom", function(){
                if (d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey){
                // TODO  the internal d3 state is still changing
                return false;
                } else{
                thisGraph.zoomed.call(thisGraph);
                }
                return true;
            })
            .on("zoomstart", function(){
                var ael = d3.select("#" + thisGraph.consts.activeEditId).node();
                if (ael){
                ael.blur();
                }
                if (!d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) d3.select('body').style("cursor",   "move");
            })
            .on("zoomend", function(){
                d3.select('body').style("cursor", "auto");
            });

        svg.call(dragSvg).on("dblclick.zoom", null);

        // listen for resize
        window.onresize = function(){thisGraph.updateWindow(svg);};

        // handle download data
        d3.select("#download-input").on("click", function(){
        var saveEdges = [];
        thisGraph.edges.forEach(function(val, i){
            saveEdges.push({source: val.source.id, target: val.target.id});
        });
        var blob = new Blob([window.JSON.stringify({"nodes": thisGraph.nodes, "edges": saveEdges})], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, "mydag.json");
        });


        // handle uploaded data
        d3.select("#upload-input").on("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("hidden-file-upload").click();
        });
        d3.select("#hidden-file-upload").on("change", function(){
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            var uploadFile = this.files[0];
            var filereader = new window.FileReader();

            filereader.onload = function(){
            var txtRes = filereader.result;
            // TODO better error handling
            try{
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(txtRes);
                thisGraph.deleteGraph(true);
                thisGraph.nodes = jsonObj.nodes;
                thisGraph.setIdCt(jsonObj.nodes.length + 1);
                var newEdges = jsonObj.edges;
                newEdges.forEach(function(e, i){
                newEdges[i] = {source: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function(n){return n.id == e.source;})[0],
                            target: thisGraph.nodes.filter(function(n){return n.id == e.target;})[0]};
                });
                thisGraph.edges = newEdges;
                thisGraph.updateGraph();
            }catch(err){
                window.alert("Error parsing uploaded file\nerror message: " + err.message);
                return;
            }
            };
            filereader.readAsText(uploadFile);

        } else {
            alert("Your browser won't let you save this graph -- try upgrading your browser to IE 10+ or Chrome or Firefox.");
        }

        });

        // handle delete graph
        d3.select("#delete-graph").on("click", function(){
        thisGraph.deleteGraph(false);
        });
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.setIdCt = function(idct){
        this.idct = idct;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.consts =  {
        selectedClass: "selected",
        connectClass: "connect-node",
        circleGClass: "conceptG",
        graphClass: "graph",
        activeEditId: "active-editing",
        BACKSPACE_KEY: 8,
        DELETE_KEY: 46,
        ENTER_KEY: 13,
        nodeRadius: 50
    };

    /* PROTOTYPE FUNCTIONS */

    GraphCreator.prototype.dragmove = function(d) {
        var thisGraph = this;
        if (thisGraph.state.shiftNodeDrag){
        thisGraph.dragLine.attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node())[0] + ',' + d3.mouse(this.svgG.node())[1]);
        } else{
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y +=  d3.event.dy;
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.deleteGraph = function(skipPrompt){
        var thisGraph = this,
            doDelete = true;
        if (!skipPrompt){
        doDelete = window.confirm("Press OK to delete this graph");
        }
        if(doDelete){
        thisGraph.nodes = [];
        thisGraph.edges = [];
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
    };

    /* select all text in element: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element */
    GraphCreator.prototype.selectElementContents = function(el) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    };


    /* insert svg line breaks: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241475/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-labels-in-d3-charts */
    GraphCreator.prototype.insertTitleLinebreaks = function (gEl, title) {
        var words = title.split(/\s+/g),
            nwords = words.length;
        var el = gEl.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor","middle")
            .attr("dy", "-" + (nwords-1)*7.5);

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
        if (i > 0)
            tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
        }
    };


    // remove edges associated with a node
    GraphCreator.prototype.spliceLinksForNode = function(node) {
        var thisGraph = this,
            toSplice = thisGraph.edges.filter(function(l) {
        return (l.source === node || l.target === node);
        });
        toSplice.map(function(l) {
        thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(l), 1);
        });
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectEdge = function(d3Path, edgeData){
        var thisGraph = this;
        d3Path.classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, true);
        if (thisGraph.state.selectedEdge){
        thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
        }
        thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = edgeData;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.replaceSelectNode = function(d3Node, nodeData){
        var thisGraph = this;
        d3Node.classed(this.consts.selectedClass, true);
        if (thisGraph.state.selectedNode){
        thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
        }
        thisGraph.state.selectedNode = nodeData;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromNode = function(){
        var thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.circles.filter(function(cd){
        return cd.id === thisGraph.state.selectedNode.id;
        }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
        thisGraph.state.selectedNode = null;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.removeSelectFromEdge = function(){
        var thisGraph = this;
        thisGraph.paths.filter(function(cd){
        return cd === thisGraph.state.selectedEdge;
        }).classed(thisGraph.consts.selectedClass, false);
        thisGraph.state.selectedEdge = null;
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.pathMouseDown = function(d3path, d){
        var thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        state.mouseDownLink = d;

        if (state.selectedNode){
        thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
        }

        var prevEdge = state.selectedEdge;
        if (!prevEdge || prevEdge !== d){
        thisGraph.replaceSelectEdge(d3path, d);
        } else{
        thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
        }
    };

    // mousedown on node
    GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseDown = function(d3node, d){
        var thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        state.mouseDownNode = d;
        if (d3.event.shiftKey){
        state.shiftNodeDrag = d3.event.shiftKey;
        // reposition dragged directed edge
        thisGraph.dragLine.classed('hidden', false)
            .attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d.x + ',' + d.y);
        return;
        }
    };

    /* place editable text on node in place of svg text */
    GraphCreator.prototype.changeTextOfNode = function(d3node, d){
        var thisGraph= this,
            consts = thisGraph.consts,
            htmlEl = d3node.node();
        d3node.selectAll("text").remove();
        var nodeBCR = htmlEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
            curScale = nodeBCR.width/consts.nodeRadius,
            placePad  =  5*curScale,
            useHW = curScale > 1 ? nodeBCR.width*0.71 : consts.nodeRadius*1.42;
        // replace with editableconent text
        var d3txt = thisGraph.svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
            .data([d])
            .enter()
            .append("foreignObject")
            .attr("x", nodeBCR.left + placePad )
            .attr("y", nodeBCR.top + placePad)
            .attr("height", 2*useHW)
            .attr("width", useHW)
            .append("xhtml:p")
            .attr("id", consts.activeEditId)
            .attr("contentEditable", "true")
            .text(d.title)
            .on("mousedown", function(d){
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on("keydown", function(d){
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
                if (d3.event.keyCode == consts.ENTER_KEY && !d3.event.shiftKey){
                this.blur();
                }
            })
            .on("blur", function(d){
                d.title = this.textContent;
                thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3node, d.title);
                d3.select(this.parentElement).remove();
            });
        return d3txt;
    };

    // mouseup on nodes
    GraphCreator.prototype.circleMouseUp = function(d3node, d){
        var thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state,
            consts = thisGraph.consts;
        // reset the states
        state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
        d3node.classed(consts.connectClass, false);

        var mouseDownNode = state.mouseDownNode;

        if (!mouseDownNode) return;

        thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);

        if (mouseDownNode !== d){
        // we're in a different node: create new edge for mousedown edge and add to graph
        var newEdge = {source: mouseDownNode, target: d};
        var filtRes = thisGraph.paths.filter(function(d){
            if (d.source === newEdge.target && d.target === newEdge.source){
            thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(d), 1);
            }
            return d.source === newEdge.source && d.target === newEdge.target;
        });
        if (!filtRes[0].length){
            thisGraph.edges.push(newEdge);
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
        } else{
        // we're in the same node
        if (state.justDragged) {
            // dragged, not clicked
            state.justDragged = false;
        } else{
            // clicked, not dragged
            if (d3.event.shiftKey){
            // shift-clicked node: edit text content
            var d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(d3node, d);
            var txtNode = d3txt.node();
            thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
            txtNode.focus();
            } else{
            if (state.selectedEdge){
                thisGraph.removeSelectFromEdge();
            }
            var prevNode = state.selectedNode;

            if (!prevNode || prevNode.id !== d.id){
                thisGraph.replaceSelectNode(d3node, d);
            } else{
                thisGraph.removeSelectFromNode();
            }
            }
        }
        }
        state.mouseDownNode = null;
        return;

    }; // end of circles mouseup

    // mousedown on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseDown = function(){
        this.state.graphMouseDown = true;
    };

    // mouseup on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgMouseUp = function(){
        var thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state;
        if (state.justScaleTransGraph) {
        // dragged not clicked
        state.justScaleTransGraph = false;
        } else if (state.graphMouseDown && d3.event.shiftKey){
        // clicked not dragged from svg
        var xycoords = d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node()),
            d = {id: thisGraph.idct++, title: consts.defaultTitle, x: xycoords[0], y: xycoords[1]};
        thisGraph.nodes.push(d);
        thisGraph.updateGraph();
        // make title of text immediently editable
        var d3txt = thisGraph.changeTextOfNode(thisGraph.circles.filter(function(dval){
            return dval.id === d.id;
        }), d),
            txtNode = d3txt.node();
        thisGraph.selectElementContents(txtNode);
        txtNode.focus();
        } else if (state.shiftNodeDrag){
        // dragged from node
        state.shiftNodeDrag = false;
        thisGraph.dragLine.classed("hidden", true);
        }
        state.graphMouseDown = false;
    };

    // keydown on main svg
    GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyDown = function() {
        var thisGraph = this,
            state = thisGraph.state,
            consts = thisGraph.consts;
        // make sure repeated key presses don't register for each keydown
        if(state.lastKeyDown !== -1) return;

        state.lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;
        var selectedNode = state.selectedNode,
            selectedEdge = state.selectedEdge;

        switch(d3.event.keyCode) {
        case consts.BACKSPACE_KEY:
        case consts.DELETE_KEY:
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        if (selectedNode){
            thisGraph.nodes.splice(thisGraph.nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
            thisGraph.spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
            state.selectedNode = null;
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
        } else if (selectedEdge){
            thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(selectedEdge), 1);
            state.selectedEdge = null;
            thisGraph.updateGraph();
        }
        break;
        }
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyUp = function() {
        this.state.lastKeyDown = -1;
    };

    // call to propagate changes to graph
    GraphCreator.prototype.updateGraph = function(){

        var thisGraph = this,
            consts = thisGraph.consts,
            state = thisGraph.state;

        thisGraph.paths = thisGraph.paths.data(thisGraph.edges, function(d){
        return String(d.source.id) + "+" + String(d.target.id);
        });
        var paths = thisGraph.paths;
        // update existing paths
        paths.style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed(consts.selectedClass, function(d){
            return d === state.selectedEdge;
        })
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        });

        // add new paths
        paths.enter()
        .append("path")
        .style('marker-end','url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed("link", true)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        })
        .on("mousedown", function(d){
            thisGraph.pathMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
            }
        )
        .on("mouseup", function(d){
            state.mouseDownLink = null;
        });

        // remove old links
        paths.exit().remove();

        // update existing nodes
        thisGraph.circles = thisGraph.circles.data(thisGraph.nodes, function(d){ return d.id;});
        thisGraph.circles.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});

        // add new nodes
        var newGs= thisGraph.circles.enter()
            .append("g");

        newGs.classed(consts.circleGClass, true)
        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            if (state.shiftNodeDrag){
            d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, true);
            }
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            d3.select(this).classed(consts.connectClass, false);
        })
        .on("mousedown", function(d){
            thisGraph.circleMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
        })
        .on("mouseup", function(d){
            thisGraph.circleMouseUp.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
        })
        .call(thisGraph.drag);

        newGs.append("circle")
        .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));

        newGs.each(function(d){
        thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3.select(this), d.title);
        });

        // remove old nodes
        thisGraph.circles.exit().remove();
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.zoomed = function(){
        this.state.justScaleTransGraph = true;
        d3.select("." + this.consts.graphClass)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    };

    GraphCreator.prototype.updateWindow = function(svg){
        var docEl = document.documentElement,
            bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var x = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth;
        var y = window.innerHeight|| docEl.clientHeight|| bodyEl.clientHeight;
        svg.attr("width", x).attr("height", y);
    };



    /**** MAIN ****/

    // warn the user when leaving
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return "Make sure to save your graph locally before leaving :-)";
    };

    var docEl = document.documentElement,
        bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var width = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth || bodyEl.clientWidth,
        height =  window.innerHeight|| docEl.clientHeight|| bodyEl.clientHeight;

    var xLoc = width/2 - 25,
        yLoc = 100;

    // initial node data
    var nodes = [];
    var edges = [];

    /** MAIN SVG **/
    var svg = d3.select(settings.appendElSpec).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
    var graph = new GraphCreator(svg, nodes, edges);
        graph.setIdCt(2);
    graph.updateGraph();
    // })(window.d3, window.saveAs, window.Blob);
    })(window.d3, window.Blob);


</script>

<!-- <div id ="graphViewer"> -->
    <body>
        <div id="graph"></div>
        <div id="toolbox">
          <input type="file" id="hidden-file-upload"><input id="upload-input" type="image" title="upload graph" src="upload-icon.png" alt="upload graph"> <input type="image" id="download-input" title="download graph" src="download-icon.png" alt="download graph"> <input type="image" id="delete-graph" title="delete graph" src="trash-icon.png" alt="delete graph"> 
        </div>
        <!-- <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>     -->
        <!-- <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/filesaver.js/0.1/FileSaver.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="src/pages/Bayesian/BayesianOverallView.svelte"></script> -->
    </body>
<!-- </div> -->

  
  <style>

        #graphViewer {
            border: 1px red;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }
        body{
            margin: 2rem;
            padding: 2rem;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        p{
            color: red;
        }

        body{
            border: 1px red;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        p{ 
            text-align: center; 
            overflow: overlay;
            position: relative;
        }

        body{
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248)
        }

        #toolbox{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            margin-left: 1em;
            border: 2px solid #EEEEEE;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 1em;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #toolbox input{
            width: 30px;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }
        #toolbox input:hover{
            opacity: 1;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #hidden-file-upload{
            display: none;
        }

        #download-input{
            margin: 0 0.5em;
        }

        .conceptG text{
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        marker{
            fill: #333;
        }

        g.conceptG circle{
            fill: #F6FBFF;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }

        g.conceptG:hover circle{
            fill: rgb(200, 238, 241);
        }

        g.selected circle{
            fill: rgb(250, 232, 255);
        }
        g.selected:hover circle{
            fill: rgb(250, 232, 255);
        }

        path.link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 6px;
            cursor: default;
        }

        path.link:hover{
            stroke: rgb(94, 196, 204);
        }

        g.connect-node circle{
            fill: #BEFFFF;
        }

        path.link.hidden{
            stroke-width: 0;
        }

        path.link.selected {
            stroke: rgb(229, 172, 247);
        }
  </style>
```

I tried the above code and expected similar functionality to show up in the component view but this did not work.

Comment: "this cool javascript library" - It's not a library, it's an application.

Comment: You really should not use this. It has not been updated in 8 years and is not intended to be used like this. Either fully migrate it to how Svelte is supposed to be used or find an actual library.

Comment: Mate you say you want it to be it's own component inside your site but haven't even changed out the body tags to something else. At least give it a go yourself before pasting it here for others to figure out for you