# Set text width or put text in a div

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to be able to set the width of a text element in D3. For now I have some text in a circle but I cannot set the width of this element. (let's say that `nodeEnter` is a node in my graph)

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){return d.radius+"px";});

/* Add text in middle of circle */
nodeEnter.append('text')
    .text("this is a very long text");
```

What I would like is to find a simple way of setting the width of that text element (with the overflow going down, as in a simple `div`). The way I have right now is the following:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){return d.radius+"px";});

/* Add text in middle of circle */ 
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 130)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("class", "myCSS")
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .html("this is a very long text");
```

However I don't think that it is the best solution, for example everything I set in `myCSS` is overwriten. Moreover I don't know how to center the foreign Object in the circle (especially on the x axis).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe similar to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want automatic line wrapping, `foreignObject` with a `div` is the way to go. The problems you mention can be fixed relatively easily. While you're setting `myCSS` for the svg element, you're not setting it for the `div`. If you add the line to set the CSS class after appending the `div`, it should pick up the settings.

The easiest way to center the text is probably to set the size of the `div` to touch the edges of the circle and add the CSS to center the text within the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just creating circles, you could always just use regular HTML elements to create the circles and absolute positioning to position them.

http://jsfiddle.net/FPkxV/

HTML:

```
<p><span></span><span>This is some text which will wrap if it gets too long!</span></p>​
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 10px sans-serif; }
p { 
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; }
p span { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
p span:first-child { height: 100px; }
```

This also has the advantage of [being supported on IE7 and IE8.](http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG)

Comment: This is a really nice trick. I am now looking for the best way to integrate it in my d3 environment. Do you have any idea?

Comment: [tag:d3] can use [tag:SVG], [tag:Canvas], plain [tag:HTML]... it doesn't matter. What do you mean by your [tag:d3] environment? Does that mean you want to keep everything in [tag:SVG]?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the vague comment.