# How to implement SVG 1.2 Tiny textArea?

Tags: html, svg

I recently browsed on the internet that
there is a [textArea local to SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#TextInAnArea) (I might need this for text-wrapping purpose)

I used the example and tested it on Chrome inside the HTML5 element,
but it won't display the textArea element,
anyone know how to properly implement the SVG textArea?
or is it possible that the SVG 1.2 tiny is not supported yet? (I only worked with the usual SVG 1.1)

Comment: what about <foreignObject> and a html textarea inside?

Comment: I already saved that as a last resort, but it would be more efficient if I use the element from svg instead of foreignObject inside the svg

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text

Answer (score 13):

Check if the UA supports the [http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/feature/1.2/#TextFlow](http://w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/feature.html#specific) feature string and display an SVG textArea if it does, otherwise display an html textarea inside a foreignObject e.g.

```
<switch>
    <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/feature/1.2/#TextFlow">
        <textArea width="200" height="300">whatever</textArea>
    </g>
    <foreignObject width="200" height="300">
        <textArea xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 200px;height: 300px">otherwise</textArea>
    </foreignObject>
</switch>
```

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and IE and none support the textflow feature string, do you know if any browser feature it?

Comment: Only Opera at the moment AFAIK.

Comment: The requiredFeatures string is correct, but http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/feature.html#specific is a better reference.

Comment: Note: you also need to specify width and height on the foreignObject element for it to be visible.

Comment: Note: IE doesn't support foreign object.

Comment: Just tried this in Chrome, and it still doesn't work.