# textArea SVG element not appearing in FireFox

Tags: svg

I'm trying to wrap text automatically since I won't know what the text is ahead of time.

I tried using the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140493/how-to-implement-svg-1-2-tiny-textarea) question, but nothing shows up. Here is my sample code so far:

```
  <svg id="viz" style="margin:auto; position:fixed; height:100%; width:100%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <switch>
          <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/feature/1.2/#TextFlow">
              <textArea width="200" height="300">whatever</textArea>
          </g>
          <foreignObject width="200" height="300">
              <textArea xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 200px;height: 300px">otherwise</textArea>
          </foreignObject>
      </switch>
  </svg>
```

I am rendering this SVG in FireFox (since its part of a web page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox implements some parts of SVG 2 and [dropping support for requiredFeatures](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#ConditionalProcessingOverview) is one part of SVG 2 that it has implemented.

> Previous versions of SVG included a third conditional processing attribute, requiredFeatures. This was intended to allow authors to provide fallback behavior for user agents that only implemented parts of the SVG specification. Unfortunately, poor specification and implementation of this attribute made it unreliable as a test of feature support.

That means that the first part of the switch now applies when at the time I wrote the answer to the other question, it didn't. The answer is to remove the switch and the first element as nobody implements SVG 1.2 textArea any more.

```html
<svg id="viz" style="margin:auto; position:fixed; height:100%; width:100%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <foreignObject width="200" height="300">
              <textArea xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 200px;height: 300px">otherwise</textArea>
          </foreignObject>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Ah, turns out that's not the `textArea` I was after. But thank you.