# Svg- foreignObject placed with d3 does not render

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

[Check out my jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/afoguj/2/edit)

I would like some wrapping text. Following the [recommendation from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text) I created a foreignObject and appended it with a 'p' element.

My text does not show up at all.

Now, when I do the EXACT SAME thing in markup it shows (I just take the generated svg code and plop it into the svg body).

Heck, if I right go to devtools, right click on the svg, choose "edit as html" and insert a new line before the `</svg>` closing brace, my text shows up.

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
 .append('p')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
```

with

```
.append('xhtml:p')
```

Namespaces are special things when creating nodes in javascript and can't be treated as attributes. d3 uses the above syntax to cope with that.