# d3 js line breaks not working in text using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Why doesn't the break tag render?

I've read several answers on SO, and tried a variety of different approaches, with no luck.

This fiddle shows the current fully functioning d3.js sample, with the problem of break tag not rendering:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsnqx/1/

The relevant bit of code is here:

```
node.insert("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .html(function(d) { 
        var html = d.name.split(" ");
        return html.join("<br>");
    });
```

Note: if any of you d3 experts have additional comments / observations about the code I've constructed, please let me know.  When I'm done, I want this code to be first-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put HTML directly into SVG.  You need to use the `foreignObject` element to embed HTML.  Here's another question that addresses this: [Auto line-wrapping in SVG text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text).

Comment: Thank you.  As that answer refers to the xml, do you have any code that explains how to achieve this with javascript / css?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your d3 code is building the XML with javascript when it modifies the DOM.

Comment: I figured it out.  BTW, what I mean is: that answer shows the XML structure, it doesn't show the d3 scripting that would generate that structure.  That took a fair amount of fiddling to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake, I wanted to post the eventual d3 / js code that I ended up using to generate the XML (per @ScottCameron answer):

```
node.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("width", "120")
    .attr("height", "120")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-60,-60)")
    .html(function(d) { 
        var html = d.name.split(" ");
        return html.join("<br>");
    });
```