# How can I give <g> fixed width?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have legend of a chart like this with svg:

```
  <g class="legend">
    <g class="scrollbox">
      <g><text>aaa</text></g>
      <g><text>bbb</text></g>
      <g><text>ccc</text></g>
      <g><text>ddd</text></g>
      <g><text>eee</text></g>
    </g>
  </g>
```

this would good if each text is not really long, but if text is long, it make legend(g) unnecessary bigger.

So I want legend (g) to have fixed width, and if text inside it is long, I want it to be wrapped.

How can I achieve this?
I know that I cannot really give style to `<g>`, so append some elements inside legend to achieve this?

Comment: SVG does not support auto wrapping, you'd have to wrap the text yourself by cutting it up into separate elements.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style>
text {
    white-space: wrap;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css rule to the `<text>` to add ellipses to really long text.

Just add the class `truncate` to your elements or drop the class specificity-modifier from the rule below.

```css
text.truncate {
  width: /* Your preferred width */;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Alternatively:

```css
.legend .scrollbox text { /* ... */ }
```