# Converting svg to png while text wrapping using `shape-inside` text property

Tags: python, svg, rendering, cairo, inkscape

I have an svg I made in Inkscape that uses the `shape-inside` text property to wrap text. When I output it to png using `cairosvg`, `svglib`, or `wand` the text bleeds off the image because `shape-inside` is not respected:

[image]

When I convert it to png using the Inkscape CLI the shape-inside is respected:

[image]

The text in the card is programmatically generated. The card text designer has no idea the width of the text area, and therefore cannot manually add newlines.

Currently, I call Inkscape using `os.system("inkscape input.svg output.png")`, but that means my python package depends on Inkscape being installed and installed in such a way that its available to the command line. Asking my users to install Inkscape is lame and will confuse many.

[The shape-inside feature is in SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextShapeInside).

My goals are:

- Convert svg to png using only python (no calling programs that may not be installed)
- Structure my svgs (using something such as `shape-inside`) so that it wraps text automatically, without baking cosmetic newlines into my card games rules

Comment: As far as I know Inkscape is the only software that supports shape-inside. Nothing else even plans to support it.

Comment: Do you know of another programmatic way of text wrapping?

Comment: use html in foreignObject

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text