# Is it possible to set a svg's <text>/<tspan> to a fixed width?

Tags: css, svg

I want to align a text to the right and in this case I have to make the text in a fixed width. Because the text content is dynamically added.

```
<text>
  <tspan x="421" y="15" text-anchor="right"
     baseline-shift="0%" kerning="0" 
     font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
     font-size="12" fill="#490275" xml:space="preserve">
       This is entered by user.
</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Are you talking about text-wrapping? If so then look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475804/svg-word-wrap-show-stopper https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Wrapping_Text

Comment: Just set the font in the CSS of the SVG to `monospace` and that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your attempt is close, you're just using the wrong value for `text-anchor`. If you use `text-anchor="end"` it will align the text to the right of the element.

So, we can set the `x` position of the `tspan` to `100%`, and along with `text-anchor="end"` the text will be positioned to the right regardless of length.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="110">
  <text>
  <tspan x="100%" y="15" text-anchor="end"
     baseline-shift="0%" kerning="0" 
     font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold"
     font-size="12" fill="#490275" xml:space="preserve">
       This is entered by user.
</tspan>
</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```